# 20.04 - Soft lockup

Tags: boot, 20.04, restart

Very new to Ubuntu (linux) so please forgive me if I need specific instructions...

Trying to get Ubuntu 20.04 onto following device:
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91064/intel-compute-stick-stk1a32sc.html

Previous version LTS 18.04 works fine when restarting.

However, after installing 20.04 from fresh (not upgrading) when I shutdown the Stick via the menu it shutdowns as intended, but if I try to do a 'restart' when it restarts, it gets stuck at boot with a Soft lockup error. See image below:

[image: Boot error]

Going to be honest- completely out my depth with troubleshooting Linux OS. I have checked the `dmesg` log and can't see any mention of this error. Which is confusing as my understanding was this the Windows equivalent of a dump file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

RedArrow.

P.s
Here is the [dmseg](http://pastebin.pl/view/ea4c77e0) log file:

Comment: Looks like it boots(otherwise you wouldn't be able to get the dmesg log).So just get a newer kernel like [v5.6](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6/linux-image-unsigned-5.6.0-050600-generic_5.6.0-050600.202003292333_amd64.deb) and install it , then reboot and in the grub2 menu select the newer kernel.```Soft lockup```  is caused when something goes into one CPU thread in order to get executed but doesn't get out after finishing the execution(happens only in kernel)So definitely it's a bug and I don't think you can do anything to get rid of that except installing another kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it boots(otherwise you wouldn't be able to get the dmesg log).So just get a newer kernel like [v5.6](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6/linux-image-unsigned-5.6.0-050600-generic_5.6.0-050600.202003292333_amd64.deb) and install it , then reboot and in the grub2 menu select the newer kernel.

**Soft lockup** happens when something goes into one CPU thread in order to get executed but doesn't get out after finishing the execution(happens only in kernel because you can disable [Preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) or [Interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769768/why-disabling-interrupts-disables-kernel-preemption-and-how-spin-lock-disables-p) only in kernel not in userspace.It's the responsibility of the kernel programmer to call for example [schedule()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.5/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L4151) or a similar procedure when necessary).

So definitely it's a bug and I don't think you can do anything to get rid of that except installing another kernel.

You might also want to install additional [kernel modules](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6/linux-modules-5.6.0-050600-generic_5.6.0-050600.202003292333_amd64.deb).

And if you use specific proprietary drivers like Nvidia GPU drivers or Broadcom STA drivers, in order to be able to use them with your newer kernel you **might** need to install [kernel headers](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6/linux-headers-5.6.0-050600-generic_5.6.0-050600.202003292333_amd64.deb) and then reconfigure the driver's **dkms** package.

For instance you might need to do this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-driver-VERSION
```

or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi - Many thanks for your reply Parsa - I tried doing as you suggested and updating the Kernal. However, I wasn't successful in install 5.6 as you orignally suggested, so did some research and found an article to update kernal using mainline. I did that, and installed the latest stable release (5.7.8) and when rebooting it still shows this soft lockup error. So doesn't seem like the Kernal version helped.

Do you have any other suggestions? The stick I've install ubuntu on doesn't have Nvidia gfx as it uses intergrated GFX.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error message and I was running Ubuntu 20.04 within a VM on VMware Workstation 16 Pro build-17966106.

Enabling "Virtualize Intel VT-x/ or AMD-V/RVI" within the VM settings-Hardware Tab under "Processors" did the trick for me.